# plunker node js jitsu error when start application

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, nodejitsu, iced-coffeescript, plunker

I getting errors during start jitsu server.

Please guide me

```
{"message":"Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'local'","code":500}


err Mon, 11 Nov 2013 13:13:09 GMT TypeError: Object # has no method 'local'
at Object.module.exports.middleware [as handle]
(/opt/run/snapshot/package/servers/www/middleware/expose.coffee:3:5)
at next (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
at multipart (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:90:37)
at module.exports
(/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9)
at urlencoded (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:49:37)
at module.exports
(/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:55:7)
at json (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:51:37)
at Object.bodyParser [as handle]
(/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:53:5)
at next (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
at Object.cookieParser [as handle]
(/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:60:5)
at next (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
at Object.exports.send [as oncomplete]
(/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:139:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `res.locals` (**plural**) not `res.local`

Since this is still not clear enough for @Marco,

- open `expose.coffee` in your text editor
- on line 3, change the word "local" to "locals"
- save and retry

Comment: It does. His code has a bug. The bug is he's using the wrong name for a function as indicated in the stack trace. I point this out and tell him the correct name. What's the problem?